# Can I view iOS documentation from Android Studio IDE for Kotlin Multiplatform?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform

My background is on Android development but I started recently working with KMM.

When developing apps using KMM I find myself wanting to check the iOS SDK code quite often. Is there a way to access this code? I guess it's not open source, so the answer should be no, right?

Is there a way to at least have access to something like the Javadocs for iOS from inside the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building for iOS targets, the SDK should be available as platform libraries(see [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-platform-libs.html)). In general, this code can be reached by importing `platform.<libname>.<class>`, IDEA and Android Studio should resolve and suggest them correctly. However, platform libs do not provide any docs at this moment.
The recommended approach is to use Objective-C API description in Apple's documentation to learn more about particular classes and methods, e.g. [NSApplication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication?language=objc).